# $\lfloor \frac{n}{27} \rfloor=\lfloor \frac{n}{28} \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

If $n$ be a non-negative integer then solve for $n$:$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{27} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{28} \right\rfloor$$

My Attempt:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{27} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{28} \right\rfloor=k$$

I am able to get $k<28$ but can't proceed from here

Comment: Plugin many different numbers for $n$, can you observe a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $${n\over 28}\geq  [{n\over 28}] = [{n\over 27}] > {n\over 27}-1$$

so $n< 27\cdot 28$...

Another hint: Draw a graph of $[{n\over 28}]$ and $[{n\over 27}]$.